# How do display the word document in asp.net page retrieved from SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

How do display a Word document on an asp.net page retrieved from a SQL Server database table?

I have uploaded the word document into database, please see the code,

Now I want to display the word document details in gridview, when I click the word document name in the gridview then the word document should display in webpage. Please help me how to do this.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    string contenttype = String.Empty;

    //Set the contenttype based on File Extension
    switch (ext)
    {
        case ".doc":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            break;

        case ".docx":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            break;

        case ".xls":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;

        case ".xlsx":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;

        case ".jpg":
            contenttype = "image/jpg";
            break;

        case ".png":
            contenttype = "image/png";
            break;

        case ".gif":
            contenttype = "image/gif";
            break;

        case ".pdf":
            contenttype = "application/pdf";
            break;
    }

    if (contenttype != String.Empty)
    {
        Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

        //insert the file into database
        string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data)" +
                          " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contenttype;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;

        InsertUpdateData(cmd);

        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblMessage.Text = "File format not recognised." +
                          " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats";
    }
}

private Boolean InsertUpdateData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("user id=sa;password=123;database=Shashank;data source=Shashank");

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: its saved in string format in db ? If so set <div id='mydiv'> as runat server and give the content to div as . mydiv.innerhtml=COntent;

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you have to convert the word document to .html to display it in a web page itself. You can check out this article that shows you how to do it. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/munnamax/WordToHtml03252007065157AM/WordToHtml.aspx

I guess what I would do is convert the ms doc file to HTML at upload and then store that along with the .doc or .docx. The HTML you would select and display it in an iframe and the actual .doc file you could use if the user wanted to download it.